# Hibernate createQuery remove() in WHERE condition

Tags: java, hibernate

let's say I have entity Person.

When I try to use with hibernate createQuery, it remove ( ) in where condition. Example:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Person WHERE name=? OR (id=? AND active=?)");
query.setParameter(1, "Test");
query.setParameter(2, 1);
query.setParameter(3, 1);
// and so on
```

When I open debug sql output in hibernate, it produces

```
where person0_.`name`=? or person0_.`id`=? and person0_.`active`=?
```

Cause I put () inside the where condition, the output should be

```
where person0_.`name`=? or (person0_.`id`=? and person0_.`active`=?)
```

why the () in where condition is removed? or am I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: Does it help if you add a couple of brackets/paranthesis around name=?, so that you'll end up with: FROM Person WHERE (name=?) OR (id=? AND active=?). Just a wild guess though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AND has a higher precedence than OR in SQL so the two statements are equivalent. Hibernate removes the unnecessary parentheses.

Comment: I think it's different meaning.  Example: I just want to get the (person with username 'admin') OR (person with id=10 and active=1).  in this case, there is 2 person will be allowed.

Comment: Wait, i think you're right... when I try another sql grouping, hibernate not removes the parentheses.